# Convert UTF-8 accents to malformed ISO accents

Tags: php

I'm in an UTF-8 project.
I have data from an old ISO project where accents are bad encoded (Ã©,Ã¨...), I don't want to convert the ISO data but I need to match some data between the 2 databases.

So I got to transform a "é" into a "Ã©" (and so on..)

I tried to convert to ISO but I never succeeded to obtain the weird encodage.

Is there a way to convert these accents while staying in UTF-8 file encodage ?

Comment: It really depends on which ISO encoding you were working with, but to (invalidly) "downgrade" from UTF-8 you could trying something like `mb_convert_encoding('é', 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1')`. You can see it here: https://3v4l.org/3TIWI

Comment: Oh ! Thank you Chris, this is what I was looking for ! You can submit it as an answer so I can flag this question as solved ! Thank you again !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on which ISO encoding you were working with, but to (invalidly) "downgrade" from UTF-8 you could trying something like `mb_convert_encoding('é', 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1')`, [demo here](https://3v4l.org/3TIWI)